# Getting Cannot read property in postman scripts when null found

Tags: rest, postman

I am getting an Error when running a script in the Postman `Tests` tab, When trying to check that a property is not `null`.

My JSON response:

```
{
    "statusMessage": "Success",
    "timeStamp": "2018-01-23 05:13:16.7",
    "numberOfRecords": 7,
    "parties": [
        {

        "shippingAddress": null,
        "shippingDetails": null,
        "paExpirationDate": "",
        "historyDate": "01/22/2018",
        "renewal": {
            "renewalRx": "N",
            "priorRxNumber": "",
            "priorSB": "",
            "priorFillNumber": ""
        },
        "noOfRefillingRemaining": "1",
        "ndc": "00074-3799-06",
        "rxId": "7004942",
        "fillingNumber": "0"
    },

    {          
        "shippingAddress": {
            "addressLine1": "2150 St",
            "addressLine2": "Home Line 2",
            "city": "Bronx",
            "state": "NY",
            "zipCode": "10453",
            "addressSeqNumber": "1",
            "medFacilityIndicator": "N"
        }
    }

]
}
```

My postman script is:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var parties = jsonData.parties;

parties.forEach(function(data){

 if(data.shippingAddress!==null && data.shippingAddress.addressLine1 !== null ){

    postman.setEnvironmentVariable("addressLine1",data.shippingAddress.addressLine1);

}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
"Error running tests for results: TypeError: Cannot read property 'addressLine1' of null"
```

Comment: can anyone  please help me out how to make null check and getting values????

Comment: Did that answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this, I changed your code slightly but this would work:

```
var parties  = pm.response.json().parties

for(i = 0; i < parties.length; i++) {
    if(parties[i].shippingAddress !== null) {
        pm.environment.set("addressLine1", parties[i].shippingAddress.addressLine1)
    }
}
```

I tested this locally with the Schema that you provided and that it wrote `2150 St` to my environment file.

The schema you posted doesn't seem to be a complete one, I *think* that the `parties` array has a `shippingAddress` property which is either `null` or it is an object containing the `shippingAddress` details - I might be wrong but I can't get my head around the data that you posted.

I don't think what you're searching on the in the `if` statement is correct and it wouldn't work the way you have it because if the first condition is null (like in your response data) it wouldn't ever meet the second condition because the object wouldn't be there and that `shippingAddress.addressLine1` reference would always show that error.

Or you could use your code like this:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody)
var parties = jsonData.parties

parties.forEach(function(data) {
    if(data.shippingAddress !== null) {
        postman.setEnvironmentVariable("addressLine1",data.shippingAddress.addressLine1)
    }
})
```

Comment: i used this but getting error "can not read property 'length of undefined'"

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: data.shippingAddress.addressLine1 this line is giving error when addressline1 is null, there i am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'addressLine1 ' of undefined

Comment: Is the data you posted correct? It looks incomplete to me or it doesn’t tell the whole story about what’s returned in the response. Can you update with a complete set rather than an edited one.

Comment: Sorry @Danny Dainton , i have not wanted to post complete data due to some policies, any how i got correct answer from you.

Comment: That doesn't stop you posting the complete schema and masking the details that you don't want to expose. It's a lot better than adding a question with invalid information. Glad you got an answer in the end.